Kernel module install test failure: FieldException: Field 'uid' on entity type 'file' references a target entity type 'user' which does not exist
I'm trying to add a really simple module install/uninstall test:
<?php

namespace Drupal\Tests\jsonapi_include\Kernel;

use Drupal\KernelTests\KernelTestBase;

/**
 * Test installation and uninstallation.
 *
 * @group jsonapi_include
 */
class JsonapiIncludeInstallTest extends KernelTestBase {

  private const MODULE_NAME = 'jsonapi_include';

  /**
   * Test that the module can be installed and uninstalled.
   */
  public function testInstallUninstall(): void {
    $this->container->get('module_installer')->install([self::MODULE_NAME]);

    $this->container->get('module_installer')->uninstall([self::MODULE_NAME]);

    // Try installing and uninstalling again.
    $this->container->get('module_installer')->install([self::MODULE_NAME]);

    $this->container->get('module_installer')->uninstall([self::MODULE_NAME]);
  }

}

However, it's failing with the following error:
There was 1 error:
1) Drupal\Tests\jsonapi_include\Kernel\JsonapiIncludeInstallTest::testInstallUninstall
Drupal\Core\Field\FieldException: Field 'uid' on entity type 'file' references a target entity type 'user' which does not exist.
/builds/project/jsonapi_include/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Field/Plugin/Field/FieldType/EntityReferenceItem.php:172
/builds/project/jsonapi_include/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Field/BaseFieldDefinition.php:668
/builds/project/jsonapi_include/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Field/BaseFieldDefinition.php:691
/builds/project/jsonapi_include/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/DefaultTableMapping.php:414
/builds/project/jsonapi_include/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorageSchema.php:975
/builds/project/jsonapi_include/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorageSchema.php:418
/builds/project/jsonapi_include/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php:1523
/builds/project/jsonapi_include/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php:1597
/builds/project/jsonapi_include/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php:1524
/builds/project/jsonapi_include/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityTypeListener.php:93
/builds/project/jsonapi_include/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityDefinitionUpdateManager.php:184
/builds/project/jsonapi_include/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Extension/ModuleInstaller.php:298
/builds/project/jsonapi_include/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/ProxyClass/Extension/ModuleInstaller.php:83
/builds/project/jsonapi_include/tests/src/Kernel/JsonapiIncludeInstallTest.php:20
/builds/project/jsonapi_include/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestResult.php:729

I've added similar tests on several modules and I haven't seen this error before.
In the past, when I had errors with such a test, it was because the dependencies weren't properly defined in composer.json.  This module depends on core's JSON:API module, but that dependency is only specified in jsonapi_include.info.yml, not composer.json. Do I need to somehow specify the dependency on core's JSON:API in composer.json (which I don't know how to do), or is this some other issue?

Adding a dependency on drupal:user to mymodule.info.yml "fixes" this, but I still don't understand why there is a dependency on the User module-- there is no reference to user or account in the module code.

Well we didn’t see your module code.

@monalisa The module in question is the JSON:API Include module. It is dependent on JSON:API, but that should be the only dependency, not User module as well.

That's it then. jsonapi module depends on the file module, which depends on the uid. Kernel tests don't resolve install dependencies. And I guess the real issue is that the file module doesn't have an explicit dependency on the user module, but should.

Thanks.  It seems that Kernel tests resolve explicit dependencies, as the Kernel test doesn't specify JSON:API or File modules, but they get installed correctly, just not User.  I opened a core issue here regarding File depending on User: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3483713

Correction: Kernel tests don't resolve install schema.
